# Implement twitter gem for oauth

Tags: oauth

Can someone point me to good twitter gem 1.2.0 implementation in rails 3?

Answer (score 1):

this is a little old but might be able to help you
its an example that shows how to verify and send a tweet, very basic but useful

https://github.com/markchang/omniauth-twitter-example

or

https://github.com/sos4nt/jack-of-all-tweets
which is a little more fleshed out (see followers, etc.) and has a live demo

Answer (score 0):

Omniauth is a pretty good implementation. I'd start by looking at the Simple Omniauth railscast to get you off the ground quickly.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth